# Intuitive understanding of open sets

Tags: general-topology

Let $M = (A,d)$ be a metric space and $U$ a subset of A such that $U$ is an open set. I can see in most cases how the intuitive explanation of this $U$ that

> one can not get out of  by moving an arbitrarily small distance from any point in

makes sense. However, I'm not sure how to make sense of this in some cases. For example, as far as I'm aware, if we let $A$ be the set of lattice points in $\mathbb{R}^2$, $M$ is still a metric space, and $A$, being a subset of itself, is an open set. While I do understand that this is the case through the formal definition of open sets, being that there is a ball centred at any point in the subset contained in $A$, I can't make sense of it intuitively. In the case described above, it seems clear that we can indeed escape $A$ by moving an arbitrarily small distance from any point in A. I have a similar concern regarding sets that seem intuitively 'discrete'.

How might I reconcile this confusion? Any advice would be appreciated as this is puzzling me greatly.

Comment: Intuitively, by moving a small distance (say, 1/2) away from any point in your A, you don't get anywhere, so you stay where you were, which means you remain in A.

Comment: In your example A is open in (A, d) but not (R^2, d). So if we look at all points in A that are within 1/2 of a point p we just get the singleton p even though there are other points in R^2 within 1/2 of p. (A, d) is in fact discrete since we have open neighborhoods around every point that are actually just singletons, so all subsets of A are open in (A, d).

Comment: Ah yes thank you both; I did think it would be something of the sort but the explicit explanation helps.

Comment: @scleaver: Would you consider writing your comment as an Answer? This would help move this Question out of the Unanswered queue.

Comment: @EricNathanStucky done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(from my comment above)

It seems like the confusion is due to conflating open sets in two different topologies. Any subset $A$ of a metric space $(M, d)$ can be seen as a metric space in its own right, and the topology induced by the restriction of $d$ to $A$ is the same as the subspace topology on $A$ as a subspace of $M$. A subset is open in this topology if it is the intersection of $A$ with an open set of $M$. In particular $A$ is always open in itself, but it doesn't have to be open in $M$.

In your example $A$ is open in $(A, d|_A)$ but not $(\mathbb{R}^2, d)$. So if we look at all points in $A$ that are within $1/2$ of a given point $p$ we just get the singleton $\{p\}$ which is contained in $A$, even though there are other points in $\mathbb{R}^2$ within $1/2$ of $p$. In fact $(A, d|_A)$ is discrete since we have open neighborhoods around every point that are actually just singletons, so all subsets of $A$ are open in $(A, d|_A)$.

Answer (score 0):

General topology will strain your intuition because it attempts to study things like continuity and "equivalent" (homeomorphic) spaces *without any notion of distance*.

The following picture from Wikipedia is very helpful:

[image]

It says that in order to study topological spaces, you have to give up any notion of angles between vectors (the inner product), lengths of vectors (the norm), and distances between points (the metric).

General topology is very general, because it makes so few assumptions, but as a result of that it really only has two tools as its disposal: set theory and cardinality. Thus, topological definitions of intuitive concepts can only be made using set theory and/or cardinality.

Intuition from a space like $\mathbb R^2$, where you have the full structure including distances, lengths angles, can be very helpful in learning topology, but you have to be very clear about which topological space you're working in.

In your case, you appear to be confusing $A$ and $\mathbb R^2$. When you're in $A$, you can't go to any place that isn't a lattice point---those places don't exist in the topological space $A$.

Comment: Surely one should include cardinality in set theory (though it's the wrong part of speech). Topology has lots of intuition and one doesn't necessarily need to use any more set theory than the basic amount required in other mathematical disciplines (obviously excluding the specific subject of set-theoretic-topology, etc.)

Comment: Fair comments. In my answer, "set theory" refers to the "naive" set theory, i.e. not the fancy stuff. I also view cardinality as part of basic set theory, but I've just found it useful to think of it as part of the toolkit for point-set topology, e.g. in the definition of compactness.